# Jquery to total up lines on dynamically generated tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, sum

I have some code that appends new table rows when data is inserted into an existing row.

You can see the code in action [here](http://www.isikhulu.co.za/testapp/).

On entering a product, the new row is appended to the table with a unique input name.

The user is then required to enter a price and qty.

What I want is a 2 step calculation. In the input box Total, I want the sum of `price * qty` for that specific row. Secondly, I want the div `grandtotal` to display the sum of all the input boxes, all dynamic to the number of rows the user inserts.

Normally I would just use:

```
function fill() {
    var txt8 = document.getElementById("TextBox8").value;
    var txt9 = document.getElementById("TextBox9").value;
    document.getElementById("TextBox10").value = txt8 + txt9;
}
```

But this is for static a static table where names and ID's are known. How do I make this work for a dynamically generated table?

Apologies, I forgot to give you the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/230/

Comment: Don't even bother giving them an `id` unless you really need it. Give each input a class that describes it...such as "item-price", "item-quantity", "item-total", etc. Then, when you're looking to get that row's Total, you can use `.closest("tr")` to get the row, `.find()` to find the specific elements (by class), and then set the Total with `.val()`. Then, when you want to get the Grand Total, just add up all the elements' values with the class "item-total".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all inputs that have an ID that starts with `linetotal`, you could write the following in jQuery:

```
$('input[id^=linetotal]')
```

Now, to calculate the total, just iterate over the collection:

```
var total = 0;
$('input[id^=linetotal]').each(function() { 
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0; 
});
```

Your output, then:

```
$('#grandtotal').text(total);
```

**Edit**

To first calculate the line totals for every line, you could iterate through them like so:

```
$('table.order-list tr').each(function() {
   var price = parseInt( $('input[name=price]', this).val(), 10 );
   var qty   = parseInt( $('input[name=qty]'  , this).val(), 10 );
   $('input[id^=linetotal]', this).val(price * qty);
});
```

Of course, you wouldn't have to iterate over all rows at all times. At the change event, you're only interested in the current row, which is accessible by `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your time and advice. I understand the logic for the grandtotal but can you assist with syntax / logic for each lines total (Price*QTY)? so before I calculate grandtotal I need to calculate each table rows linetotal. here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/230/ Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks David. I get this but cant quite get the js to fire onchange. how do I call the js to do the math and populate the linetotal box? my attempt is a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/231/. lastly, the `,10` is that the Int length? thanks again.

Comment: You're not using any change listener for that piece of code in your fiddle. You have a change listener in the code that checks whether it should add a new row, so there's an example you can look at. The `10` is the `radix` parameter; it's an instruction on how the string is to be parsed. Consider `parseInt('FF', 16)`. [Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)